# How to change nowPlayingInfo of MPNowPlayingInfoCenter retaining old artwork

Tags: objective-c, ios, mpnowplayinginfocenter

I noticed that setting new `nowPlayingInfo` of `[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter]` replaces `MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork` value every new perform `setNowPlayingInfo:`. But in standart iphone music.app it doesn't happend! So how to set `nowPlayingInfo` retaining old artwork?

```
NSMutableDictionary *mediaInfo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:recording.releaseGroup.title, MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle, recording.releaseGroup.artist.title, MPMediaItemPropertyArtist, recording.title, MPMediaItemPropertyTitle, recording.lyrics, MPMediaItemPropertyLyrics, itemsCount, MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTrackCount, itemNumber, MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTrackNumber, nil];


 self.artwork = [[[MPMediaItemArtwork alloc] initWithImage:_coverView.image] autorelease];


[mediaInfo setValue:_artwork forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];


[[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter] setNowPlayingInfo:mediaInfo];
```

This block is executed every change of track is playing

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order to get useful answers, you need to show what you've done and where you're stuck. No one will write a whole program for you, but we're happy to help with specific steps and nudges in the right direction.